# Keeping words together in WordCloud

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, information-retrieval, word-cloud

I'm working with word clouds in python, using the wordcloud library.

As an example, I want to do a wordcloud from the following list:

```
word_ls = ['orchards growers northern', 'apple orchards growers', 'threatening apple orchards']
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I generate the cloud, I can't have it consider each string individually, instead of word by word

I have tried doing the token separation differently using regexp property, though unsuccessfully (getting KeyError, with `r"\w[\w ']+"`)

Any insights?

sample wordcloud generation snippet:

```
word_text = ";".join(word_ls)
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(word_text)
wordcloud.to_file("word_test.png")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from collections import Counter

word_ls = ['orchards growers northern', 'apple orchards growers', 'threatening apple orchards']
word_could_dict = Counter(word_ls)
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(word_could_dict)
wordcloud.to_file("word_test.png")
```

[image]